# How to fill out result in MDX - Mondrian

Tags: mdx, mondrian

In MDX how do you fill out with zeros the null/empty values, example:

If I have a dimension `A` and two measures `X` and `Y`, after MDX query I got this:
("-" represents "null" or "empty" values)

```
       X   Y
A.A1   1   - 
A.A2   -   2
A.A3   -   -
```

If I use "NON EMPTY" `A.A3` is gone, but when trying to use `CoalesceEmpty` to fill out with zeros I got this:

```
       X   Y
A.A1   1   0 
A.A2   0   2
A.A3   0   0
```

Suppose that there are too many tuples like `A.A3` and I don't want to show then, how do i fill out the empty values with zero and do not show the tuples that are empty in all the columns.

the result must be:

```
       X   Y
A.A1   1   0 
A.A2   0   2
```

Note: I did try with `filter` but I didn't get any improvement

Comment: Still fairly unclear what you are trying to say or do. please try to clarify what you are trying to do? Change empty things to 0's? remove them entirely if they are all empty? etc?

Comment: i clarify my question a little, i want to "Change empty things to 0's" and "remove them entirely if they are all empty". thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that is supported in Mondrian, but in Analysis Services, you could use `HAVING` on the row axis like this:

```
SELECT {Measures.X, Measures.Y}
       ON COLUMNS,
       A.Members
       HAVING Measures.X <> 0 AND Measures.Y <> 0
       ON ROWS
  FROM MyCube
```

In contrast to `NON EMPTY` which only looks at empty (i. e. `NULL`) values, for `HAVING`, you can state the condition yourself. And in Analysis Services a numeric comparison treats `NULL` the same way as zero, hence teh above condition excludes null and zero.

Another approach - slightly depending on the client tool - would be to stay with the MDX using `NON EMPTY` and not to use `CoalesceEmpty`, but convert the NULL values to 0 via the `FORMAT_STRING`. This requires the client tool to use the format string or formatted value as delivered by the cube, and not to implement its own number formatting.

Comment: your answer is fairly correct, I solved my problem using "non empty" and format_string='#0;;;0'. Mondrian do not support "having", thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was misusing the 'FORMAT_STRING'!, i  was applying just one format, thanks to this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2715b737-a9a5-4094-8235-df71e92b7bb2/how-to-remove-null-values-in-mdx that refer to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084.aspx

the correct format for numeric values is:

> FORMAT_STRING = '#0;;;0'

where the last value is the format for null values